# JQuery Array of Deferreds, implementation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred

can anyone see any mistakes in this code? 
I use this approach throught my application, almost identically, but for some reason I simply cannot seem to resolve the main promise "a";

```
   Parser.prototype.insertSomeData = function(data)
    {
        var a = $.Deferred(),
            table = "Example",
            columns = ["col1", "col2", "col3"];

        var deferreds = [];

        // insert Data into the database
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var dfd = $.Deferred();

            deferreds.push(dfd.promise());

            item = data[i];

            database.insert(table, columns, [item.one, item.two, item.three], function(){console.log("resolved"); dfd.resolve()}, dfd.reject);
        }
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds).then(function(){console.log("it worked!"); a.resolve()});

        return a.promise();
    }
```

both the promises in the deferred array do get resolved.  So I think the problem is in the `when` Any see something I'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You coded `dfd.resolve` but this doesn't do anything more than just getting the function. You'd have to call it: `dfd.resolve()`.
2. When all deferreds are finished, you probably want to resolve `a`, not `dfd`. When `$.when` has finished, all `dfd`s have been resolved, and you probably want to resolve the master deferred (`a`) in that case.

Comment: @CrimsonChin: The `dfd` is pointing to the last item in the callback due to how scoping works in JavaScript. Wrap the `for` loop body with `(function(i) { ... })(i);`.

Comment: Ok that looks like it! I don't understand what the i has to do do with the deferred when we talk about scope here though?

Comment: @CrimsonChin: Not only `i` is scoped to the function but `dfd` as well. So in the callback you're resolving the very same deferred each time. By wrapping it in a function you create separate variables.

Comment: Oh I follow you, the dfd variable was being hoisted each time losing scope so they all pointed to the same dfd object!  I have been doing Javascript for about 5 months now and scoping really busts my balls each time

Answer (score 0):

`deferreds` only contains promises from the `dfd` object, so they are the ones getting resolved.